# Free software to draw Newman projections

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, software

I need to draw [Newman projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newman_projection) of a molecule. Particularly 1,2-dicloroethane rotamers, but have no idea if there is any program to do that kind of things.

Do you know about some program available for **Linux**?

I refer to this kind of sketch:

[image: newman_projection]

Comment: Do you use Latex? If so, the [chemmacros](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) package can do this.

Comment: Sure! You can make a `standalone` document, then convert the `pdf` to `png` using `ImageMagick` (`convert file.pdf file.png`). There is also a way to compile `latex` directly to `png` (run `latex`, then `dvipng`), but I have never used it.

Comment: My guess is, not enough people need this feature for the developers to implement it. It is however present in proprietary softwares like ChemDraw (which is, of course, not available on Linux).

Comment: [Some versions](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=3060) of ChemDraw work on Linux via Wine.

Comment: @santimirandarp [Wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software)) is under GNU LGPL, [ChemDraw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChemDraw) is obviously proprietary.

Comment: @santimirandarp How do I put this - if you have ChemDraw already, you are good, Wine is free:)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GChemPaint](https://www.nongnu.org/gchempaint/), which is available on the repositories of many popular distributions. Among its many components for drawing structures, it has a specific tool for Newman's projections.

You can add H, O and many other elements by simply right-clicking on the molecule, and it even allows you to search your molecule in databases like [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov) and [ChemSpider](http://www.chemspider.com).

A useful video tutorial can be found in [spokentutorial.org](https://spoken-tutorial.org/tutorial-search/?search_foss=GChemPaint&search_language=English)

> ## 3.11 To Add a Newman Projection
>
> To add a Newman projection, use the following tool:
>
> [image: Figure 3.28: Newman Projection Tool]
>
> This tool allows to add a Newman projection. The changes become permanent only when the mouse button is released.
>
> To add a Newman projection, click on the background. Contrarily to other tools existing atoms are never used by this tool. It creates new atoms of the current element.
>
> When the Newman projection tool is active, the toolbox looks like:
> [image: Figure 3.29: GChemPaint toolbox when the Newman projection tool is selected]
>
> #### Options for the main bond
>
> - **Bond length**
>
>   The default length of the new projected bond. This has no influence ion the drawing, but might be important when exporting to a 3d model.
> - **Bond order**
>
>   The bond order.
>
> #### Options for each atom
>
> - **Bonds number**
>
>   Number of other bonds for the atom.
> - **First bond angle**
>
>   The direction of the first bond. Angles are measured counter clockwise from horizontal right.
> - **Angle between bonds**
>
>   The angle between two consecutive bonds.
>
> #### *Warning*
>
> *This version of GChemPaint does not correctly support Newman projections with eclipsed bonds.*

> **Source: [GChemPaint manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpdug.png), pages 41-43.**

Answer (score 1):

You can visit ChemistrySteps.com and use the free drawing tool embedded in the text editor. It doesn't have the ring but you can try using the text and add "O" as the ring. It may not be the best drawing tool but it is free and you can definitely draw many different structures.